# Is it possible to iterate over serialized Python file?

Tags: python, numpy, serialization, iterator, pickle

I have a reasonably long array of events (each one being an array line), stored as `numpy.ndarray` with `pickle.dump`. Is there any way to efficiently iterate over a serialized object? The idea is very similar to iterating over a text file:

```
with open('my_file.txt', 'r') as FILE:
    for line in FILE:
        do_something(line)
```

Im just concerned about not loading the entire object into memory at once.

Comment: How did you save your array? If it was with `np.save` then you should be able to use `np.load` and specify to use memory mapping...However, depending on your use case - that may not be suitable.

Comment: @JonClements I used plain `pickle.dump(np.ndarray, FILE)` but that's open to suggestions. In which case that may lead to trouble?

Comment: I didn't say it may lead to trouble... You may be able to reduce memory overhead by memory mapping it, but depending how you want to access it - your mileage may vary... reduced performance most likely one thing to note.